# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, deployment, iis-6

I am having a terrible time deploying a web app.

**Environment**

There is an intranet site that currently has lot's of files and folders, and works fine. It was not configured to use ASP.NET, it was just plain static web pages.

This is on a Win2k3 box with IIS 6.0.

**What I have tried:**

The application works fine on my development machine. The class `Employee` is in the same directory, with the same namespace as the asp.net page that is giving me this error.

There is a directory "INFO" that I have been attempting to deploy my application to. So I have:

1. Enabled ASP.NET (confirmed)
2. Confirmed that it is using .net 2.0
3. I have right clicked the directory in IIS and clicked the button "Create" next to the greyed out "Application Name" to make it an application
4. I've compiled and deployed (using VS publish tools) the application to the INFO directory (which is a share)

... and still it is not working.

Any ideas? What else do I need to do to get this thing working??

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming all the dlls are in your bin directory, alongside the application (aspx) pages?

Comment: Well there's only one dll, the dll that the application compiles too. And I think I have it right. There is a bin directory under the INFO folder, and I have that dll copied into that bin directory.

Comment: The strange thing is that it is compiling the CS code behind page, it's just not finding the class Employee, for whatever reason. . .

Comment: Maybe the actual class file is missing? Do you see an Employee.cs file? or can you find an Employee class in the source code?

Comment: Well in addition to the dll in the bin directory, Employee.cs is actually in the INFO directory.

Comment: You don't need to have the .cs files there. They should all be compiled into the assembelies in the bin folder.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I thought I would give it a try.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this ?

`MyWebapp/bin`

MyWebapp/info/bin

Try setting the info directory to an application in IIS. The folder above it should be an application as well I think.... it's hard to know based on what you've said.

Comment: Hi Jon, I have set the INFO directory to an application, but the directory above it is not...

Comment: No it doesn't because it's just static web pages. It's only "folder" that is an actualy directory.

Comment: Hmmmm it sure sounds like a config issue. You info directory should be an application. With a bin folder, and the dll(s) in that folder. But you said something about it not compiling?

Comment: Yeah I have the INFO directory set up as an application and a virtual directory.  There is a bin folder, and it has the one dll that is created when I compile the application.